# Переустановка windows 10

Tags: windows, активация

Вообщем, на ноуте стоит официальная десятка. Хотелось бы комп прочистить, да и ssd купил.
Есть ли возможность просто переустановить винду, которая уже стоит в ноуте? Лень искать новую
, создавать образы,искать флешку,активировать,ключи выискивать. Хочется по человечески. Взять и переустановить.
Желательно все по полочкам. От меня жирный +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если бук с лицензией и не древний, то скорее всего её даже активировать не нужно, т.к. ключ вшит в сам комп. Качай инсталлятор с сайта майкрософт и пиши на флешку.